# a wifi connection that used to work is no longer recognized

Tags: networking, wireless, dell

I have a dell xps 9343 with ubuntu 15.10 ; I have a Asus RP-N53 N600 Dual-Band WLAN Repeater which I use as a wireless access point connected with a cable to my router. It used to work fine. Since a week or so the connection is not recognized anymore (not shown). My history tells me it has been 11 days ago I last connected. The wireless connection of the router itself is shown and working and other wireless connections (neighbours) are also shown. I tried deleting the connection and adding it again as if it was a hidden connection but that does not work.

The wifi connection still works fine with my android phone.

I tried:
- resetting router
- reinstall of broadcom drivers (PCI ID: 14e4:43b1 rev 03) using this:
[Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

but did not work.

Comment: what wifi card does your Dell use/have?

Comment: Have you tried resetting the router?

Comment: I just did the reset, does not solve it.

Comment: It has the Broadcom wifi card.

Answer (score 0):

As I have two of these asus repeaters I noticed the other not having the problem. It seems to be DHCP related as when I switch the location after more then an hour the problematic one is now recognized whereas the other instantaneously. After my laptop 'found' it it reappears quickly after reboot. So now it is solved for me.